# How to reference these packages with Mono in order to compile

Tags: c#, .net, mono

I'm trying to compile a C# script with Mono on Debian by command line, like this:

```
gmcs Main.cs
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Main.cs(6,14): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Drawing' does not exist in the namespace `System'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Main.cs(7,14): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Drawing' does not exist in the namespace `System'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Main.cs(12,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `iTextSharp' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
Main.cs(13,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `iTextSharp' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
Main.cs(1526,31): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Bitmap' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
Main.cs(6,14): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Drawing' does not exist in the namespace `System'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Main.cs(7,14): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Drawing' does not exist in the namespace `System'. Are you missing an assembly reference?
Main.cs(12,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `iTextSharp' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
Main.cs(13,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `iTextSharp' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?
Compilation failed: 9 error(s), 1 warnings
```

These the references at the top of `Main.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Xml;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
```

I understand that I have to tell Mono which libraries to include by adding `-pkg:whatever`. My problem is that I do not know what these libraries are called, so I don't know what command is used to include them. Actually, I don't even know whether I have to download these libraries from somewhere or whether they come with Mono.

Note also that the last 2 are the iTextSharp library, for which I have `itextsharp.dll` just placed in the same directory as the script, since I don't know what else to do with it.

Please could someone explain to me how to get the file to compile!

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Try this:

```
gmcs /reference:System.Drawing.dll /reference:itextsharp.dll Main.cs
```

With newer versions of mono, try this.

```
mcs /reference:System.Drawing.dll /reference:itextsharp.dll Main.cs
```

Comment: It worked. Thank you! I will accept your answer when the site lets me.

Comment: With new mono versions, there is only one compiler now and that is mcs.

Comment: On OSX it'd be `mcs -reference:System.Drawing.dll Main.cs`, etc. And this will find files in the same directory. Probably obvious, but you never know.

Comment: @atomicules: `mcs` accepts `/` and `-` on options as equivalent on all platforms.

Comment: `/reference` could be replaced with `/r` or `-r` for conciseness

Answer (score 7):

Here's another solution that's worked for me in a similar case where I got this error:

```
Eventdemo.cs(2,14): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Drawing' does not exist in the namespace `System'. Are you missing `System.Drawing' assembly reference?
Eventdemo.cs(3,14): error CS0234: The type or namespace name `Windows' does not exist in the namespace `System'. Are you missing an assembly reference?                           │
Eventdemo.cs(8,19): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `Form' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

I had those references in my program:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

I got the solution from [ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2124799):

```
 gmcs -pkg:dotnet *.cs
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error, and when I just needed to use System.Net.Http, I used:

```
$mcs /reference:System.Net.Http.dll Program.cs
```

and it worked fine for me. When I tried to include the full path to `System.Net.Http.dll`, it didn't work. That is to say, heads up, mono keeps track of paths. Also, I have the latest version of mono.