# How do I add json assembly to compile C# code on ubuntu terminal using mcs?

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, ubuntu-16.04, monodevelop

Command line:

```
mcs -out:Test.exe *.cs
```

Error:

> error cs0246: The type or namespace name 'Newtonsoft' could not be found. Are you missing an assemly reference

I have tried to compile a C# code that has line - " using Newtonsoft.Json; ",
because I want to use JSON commands inside, from that I know, I have to install JSON files or add it to the project. Yea, in Microsoft Visual Studio i would have just add it to the project and it's working. My question is how do I do that on Ubuntu using Terminal only? I have installed mono-complete. (To be exact - VPS, so I can compile a code anytime on my phone.) Code is for learning purposes.  I just want to know how do I make the JSON repository/assembly or whatever it's called working using mcs command.

Comment: I'm not a [tag:monodevelop] developer, but if you already have a `Newtonsoft.Json.dll` you could try to use it by following the instructions from [What is the Json.NET Mono assembly reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36550910) or [How to reference these packages with Mono in order to compile](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8264783/3744182).

Comment: Thank you for your help, it worked. I have put json.dll to the same folder where are my files and included it via reference and it compiled.