# The type or namespace name `OpenQA' could not be found

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to setup selenium chromedriver with C# in Ubuntu. I am download chromedriver and it in in current folder. When I trying to run my simple code I have a selected errors.
Note:  I am beginner in C#
I am using Ubuntu 18.04 OS

```
using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
namespace SeleniumTest
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            ChromeDriverService service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService("/home/nariko/Desktop/Csharp/printHello/", "chromedriver"); //This iss my path to chromedriver
            IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(service);
            driver.Navigate ().GoToUrl ("http://www.google.com");
        }
    }
}

I have selected errors, when I trying to run this code.

test.cs(3,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `OpenQA' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
test.cs(4,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name `OpenQA' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Just putting a file in a folder doesn't tell the C# compiler about it. You need to add a reference to the DLL. Without knowing how you're compiling, it's hard to give more advice than that. Are you using Visual Studio Code? Compiling from the command line? Something else?

Comment: (Additionally, configuring your project to use a NuGet package rather than downloading the file directly is probably a better way forward - if there *is* a NuGet package available.)

Comment: I am compilingt to mono. $ mcs test.cs  and have a errors

Comment: When I compiling selected code it works fine. using System;

namespace printHello
{
        class printHello
        {
                public static void Main (string[] args)
                {
                        Console.WriteLine ("Hello this is csharp");
                }
        }
} But when using with selenium it doesnt  work

Comment: You probably need to add a `/reference webdriver.dll`, see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/8264783/578411

Comment: assuming that webdriver.dll is in the same folder as that cs file you're compiling

Comment: When I tring to run with this command mcs /reference:System.Drawing.dll /reference:itextsharp.dll test.cs, I have other error , error CS0006: Metadata file `itextsharp.dll' could not be found

Comment: You are supposed to run `mcs /reference:webdriver.dll test.cs` but you need to have that webdriver.dll in that directory as well. If not download/nuget it first.

Comment: Where I can download  webdriver.dll file? When I download selenium for C#, there are 3 files. Selenium.WebDriverBackedSelenium.3.14.0.nupkg, Selenium.WebDriver.3.14.0.nupkg and Selenium.WebDriverBackedSelenium.3.14.0.nupkg

Comment: You can't refer to a nupkg file directly - that's a NuGet package, that you'd normally add a reference to in a project file. If you can use the .NET Core SDK instead of invoking `mcs` directly, that'll make things a lot simpler for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all,I solved my problem and use Monodevelop programm